# PHPDoc wrapper object property

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

Got a stucking situation which produces unnecessary IDE warnings and may lead to cleaning-up used code.

I think the best solution is to add some PHPDoc at the right place, but couldn't find the right place yet because of some constraints, as explained in the below examples.

IDE: PhpStorm

Result:

```php
<?php

/*
 * Generic result class, widely used, so can't touch it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
 */
class Result {
  public $data;

  public function __construct() {
    return $this;
  }

  public function setData($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
    return $this;
  }
}
```

Customer:

```
<?php

class Customer {
  public string $name  = '';
  public string $email = '';

  public function __construct() {
    $this->name = 'John Smith';
    $this->email = 'test@example.com';
  }

  public function getCustomer(): Result {
    return (new Result())->setData(new self());
  }

  public function reverseName(): string { // ❌ Unused element: 'reverseName'
    $parts = explode(' ', $this->name);
    return implode(' ', array_reverse($parts));
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$john = (new Customer())->getCustomer();
// ℹ️ $john->data is an instance of the Customer class.
// How should I tell to the IDE this ^ ❓
$reversedName = $john->data->reverseName(); // ❌ Cannot find declaration to go when trying to navigate to the method
exit($reversedName);
```

Tried many and many options, but the only one which works is by adding a PHPDoc to `Result`'s `$data` property. Can't touch it because it's widely used in the project...

**LE:**: The `Customer` class has a lot of methods similar to `reverseName()`, so assigning the `data` property to a new variable is also difficult to write: `/** @var Customer $john */ $john = (new Customer())->getCustomer()->data`;

Comment: `/** @var Customer $johnData */` `$johnData = (new Customer())->getCustomer()->data;` -- something like this. Basically: get the `$object->data` into a separate variable and typehint it.

Comment: Indeed, this works too, but there's a lot of code to be refactored. Updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Should soon be possible through Psalm or PHPstan when [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-56038) will be available (should be soon-ish).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use another PhpStorm feature called [advanced metadata](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html)﻿.

Firstly you need to configure metadata in the next way

```
namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override(\App\Result::getData(0), map(['' => '@']));
}
```

then add getter to your `Result` class

```
public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}
```

and use this getter in the next way

```
$john->getData(Customer::class)->reverseName();
```

The main idea is to use class name as an argument of the getter method and PhpStorm will know what class object this getter will return.